# Using JdbcPagingItemReader causing join statements causing MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Tags: spring-batch

I am running Spring Batch  and using `JdbcPagingItemReader`. With a sample config of :

```html
<bean id="dogQueryProvider"  class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean">
  <property name="databaseType" value="mysql" />
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="selectClause"
   value="SELECT owner.id as ownerid, first_name, last_name, dog_name " />
  <property name="fromClause"
   value="FROM dog_owner owner INNER JOIN dog ON owner.id = dog.id " />
  <property name="sortKey" value="owner.id" />
</bean>
```

I am getting an error related to:

> Column 'id' in order clause is ambiguous; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'id' in order clause is ambiguous.

Take it that `dog_owner` and `dog` tables have `id` columns. I am thinking that this is related to `AbstractSqlPagingQueryProvider.getSortKeysWithoutAliases`, which I think strips off `owner` from `owner.id` specified as `sortKey`. Any suggestions to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently this seems to be happening still in some form but there is way to craft your query so that the alias won't get removed. You rename the joined column by selecting it with different name.

Your selectClause becomes

```
SELECT owner.id, owner.first_name, owner.last_name, dog.dog_name
```

FromClause becomes

```
      FROM dog_owner owner
INNER JOIN (SELECT d2.id AS dogId, d2.dog_name
              FROM dog d2) AS dog
        ON owner.id = dog.dogId
```

Now you should be able to use "id" as sortKey as there is only one column with name "id". This works even if you add the dog.dogId into the selectClause.

Comment: why sortkey is mandatory in spring batch.. any reason?  ideally it should be optional or by default some ascending order if in case...  i don't understand the reason spring is forcing developers for sort key

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in the reasoning why it is occurring.  In your case, I'd expect using your alias to fix the issue.  So you've aliased `owner.id` as `ownerid`, however you don't use it in the `sortkey` field (or the join clause for that matter).  Use the alias and you should be ok.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I had tried that initially. I think that works for having a working query for firstPageSql query but remainingPagesSql generated seems invalid as i get something like WHERE ((ownerid > ?))  in the query causing MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'ownerid ' in 'where clause'. Not sure if am missing a config. A temporary fix was to override MySqlPagingQueryProvider. I would have thought this use case to be common

Comment: I actually think that is a bug.  I've created Jira issue BATCH-2360 to track it (https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2360).

Comment: Just FYI. I ran into the same error when testing using H2 Database. I think H2PagingQueryProvider still does not have the fix.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this issue, Spring must get your sort key from the returned result set in order to page correctly. Under the hood sort key gets used in a WHERE clause which will not work with column aliases since WHERE gets processed before SELECT statements at the database level.

Our solution was to `SELECT owner.id as "owner.id"` so that the sort key can be retrieved from the result set using the same name. Doing `SELECT owner.id` puts the column `id` into your result set which in your case leads to issues with ambiguous columns. We preferred this approach to the previous answer's nested query.