# Spring Batch: JdbcPagingItemReader does not work through setSortKeys and cast(id as unsigned)

Tags: spring-batch

I am working with `Spring Batch` version `3.0.7` with `Mysql`

I had the problem that the `person_reader` table has the `id` column defined how `varchar` and thus the following happens for a simple `select` *ordered*:

```
id
--
1
10 <--- !!!
2
3
...
```

What is need it is

```
id
--
1
2
3
...
10 <--- ok!
...
```

The **solution** is use `ORDER BY cast(id as unsigned)`

If I use `JdbcCursorItemReader` I can use in peace:

```
setSql("SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM person_reader ORDER BY cast(id as unsigned)");
```

It works fine. Until here all is ok.

**Note:** for the batch process, is very important read the data in the correct order.

The problem is with `JdbcPagingItemReader`

**First Try**:

```
    JdbcPagingItemReader<Person> itemReader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<>();
    itemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    itemReader.setPageSize(100);
    itemReader.setRowMapper(new PersonRowMapper());

    MySqlPagingQueryProvider pagingQueryProvider = new MySqlPagingQueryProvider();
    pagingQueryProvider.setSelectClause("SELECT id, first_name, last_name");
    pagingQueryProvider.setFromClause("FROM person_reader ORDER BY cast(id as unsigned)");

    Map<String, Order> sortKeys= new HashMap<>();
    sortKeys.put("id", Order.ASCENDING);
    pagingQueryProvider.setSortKeys(sortKeys);

    itemReader.setQueryProvider(pagingQueryProvider);
```

Observe:

- `setFromClause("FROM person_reader ORDER BY cast(id as unsigned)")`
- `put("id", Order.ASCENDING)`

The following error appears:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback;
bad SQL grammar [SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM person_reader ORDER BY cast(id as unsigned) ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 100];
nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException:
You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 100' at line 1
```

Has sense, the `SQL` generated `SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM person_reader ORDER BY cast(id as unsigned) ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 100` is not correct.

**Second Try**

```
    JdbcPagingItemReader<Person> itemReader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<>();
    itemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    itemReader.setPageSize(100);
    itemReader.setRowMapper(new PersonRowMapper());

    MySqlPagingQueryProvider pagingQueryProvider = new MySqlPagingQueryProvider();
    pagingQueryProvider.setSelectClause("SELECT id, first_name, last_name");
    pagingQueryProvider.setFromClause("FROM person_reader");

    Map<String, Order> sortKeys= new HashMap<>();
    sortKeys.put("cast(id as unsigned)", Order.ASCENDING);
    pagingQueryProvider.setSortKeys(sortKeys);

    itemReader.setQueryProvider(pagingQueryProvider);
```

Observe:

- `setFromClause("FROM person_reader")`
- `put("cast(id as unsigned)", Order.ASCENDING)`

The following error appears:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: StatementCallback;
uncategorized SQLException for SQL [SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM person_reader ORDER BY cast(id as unsigned) ASC LIMIT 100];
SQL state [S0022]; error code [0]; Column 'cast(id as unsigned)' not found.;
nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Column 'cast(id as unsigned)' not found.
```

Has sense about the 'missing' column

`Order` is an `enum` and thus it can't be extended.

What is the correct approach?

**Alpha**

If I use in `MySQL`'s workbench the following:

- `SELECT id, first_name, last_name, cast(id as unsigned) as sb_sort_column FROM person_reader ORDER BY sb_sort_column ASC`

It works fine. If I use:

```
MySqlPagingQueryProvider pagingQueryProvider = new MySqlPagingQueryProvider();
pagingQueryProvider.setSelectClause("SELECT id, first_name, last_name, cast(id as unsigned) as sb_sort_column");
pagingQueryProvider.setFromClause("FROM person_reader");

Map<String, Order> sortKeys= new HashMap<>();
sortKeys.put("sb_sort_column", Order.ASCENDING);
pagingQueryProvider.setSortKeys(sortKeys);

itemReader.setQueryProvider(pagingQueryProvider);
```

The following error arises:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: 
PreparedStatementCallback; 
bad SQL grammar [SELECT id, first_name, last_name, cast(id as unsigned) as sb_sort_column FROM person_reader WHERE ((sb_sort_column > ?)) ORDER BY sb_sort_column ASC LIMIT 100]; 
nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: 
Unknown column 'sb_sort_column' in 'where clause'
```

From above see carefully the 3rd line about the `sql` statement generated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39577390/spring-batch-with-column-alias-as-sort-key-malformed-where-statement

Comment: Realistically this is a problem with your data model. Can you modify the `id` column to be numeric?

Comment: Even if is possible, there are scenarios where it is not possible, such as a legacy app working with other apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**:

The link provided in the comment was useful.
It from:

- [Spring batch with column alias as sort key - malformed “where” statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39577390/spring-batch-with-column-alias-as-sort-key-malformed-where-statement)

Therefore the correct configuration is:

```
    MySqlPagingQueryProvider pagingQueryProvider = new MySqlPagingQueryProvider();
    pagingQueryProvider.setSelectClause("SELECT id, first_name, last_name, sb_sort_column");
    pagingQueryProvider.setFromClause("FROM (SELECT id, first_name, last_name, cast(id as unsigned) as sb_sort_column FROM person_reader) person_reader");

    Map<String, Order> sortKeys= new HashMap<>();
    sortKeys.put("sb_sort_column", Order.ASCENDING);
    pagingQueryProvider.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
```

**Note:** be sure to include in the `setSelectClause` method the alias column, in this case `sb_sort_column`

Answer (score 1):

[Manuel's earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44396513/6215069) will work, so removing the duplicate portion of mine...

Unfortunately, despite being functionally accurate, doing an `ORDER BY` on a function will probably run pretty poorly, since it will have to scan the entire table to do the `cast`, and I don't believe MySQL lets you create an index on function yet.

That said, as of MySQL 5.7.6, you could add a virtual column `CAST(ID as UNSIGNED) as SORT_ID` to the table and then index the virtual column.

Comment: Did you test your code? I did something similar and it does not work. Read my own answer

Comment: You put it in the `SELECT`, you didn't put the sub-select in the `FROM`

Comment: Ah, didn't see that when I was drafting my answer. I'm confused though... are you saying your answer below did or did not work? If it didn't work, what's the new stacktrace?

Comment: It works, I can't check how the correct answer until tomorrow (SO's restriction). My snippet code contains the `Java` + `sql` correct configuration. In other links just cover the `sql` part

Comment: Gotcha... I removed the duplicate portions of my answer, leaving only the portions related to mitigating performance issues. Not a concern on a small table, but probably worth adding that virtual column and index if you have a recent MySQL version and a decent volume of data.